# How is responsive voice js working with promise?

Tags: javascript, responsivevoice

I use Responsive voice (text to speech) and I have created some simple data in an array and I loop over it with a promise but when I'm putting the resolve in the method `onend` of Responsive voice it is not the end of voice and it calls the next data. Please see my code.

```
var data = [
 {'textTH': "สวัสดี ค่ะ", 'lang': "Thai Female", 'textEN': "Hello", 'langEN': "US English Female"},
 {'textTH': "สวัสดี ค่ะ", 'lang': "Thai Female", 'textEN': "Hello 2", 'langEN': "US English Female"}
];

var j = data.length;

function step2(i){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if (typeof data[i] == 'undefined'){
            reject("out of rang");
    }
    else{               
      var runEnglistSpeech = function () {
        responsiveVoice.speak(data[i].textEN, data[i].langEN, { rate: .7, onend: resolve()});
        console.log("done >>>> " + i);        
      };
        responsiveVoice.speak(data[i].textTH, data[i].lang, { rate: .9, onend: runEnglistSpeech });      
    }
  })
}

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        await step2(i);
       }
})();
```

Reponsive cdn => https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working.
Change
`responsiveVoice.speak(data[i].textEN, data[i].langEN, { rate: .7, onend: resolve()});` 
to
`responsiveVoice.speak(data[i].textEN, data[i].langEN, { rate: .7, onend: resolve});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm try to timeout and it's work but i want to have any choice for this

```
setTimeout(function(){ resolve(); }, 6000);
```